# Javascript operator with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have the below if condition. it seems it is not calculating as per my requirement.

```
if(Alert=="0" && Cci<-80 && (RSI=="Sell" || ADX=="Sell") &&(status1=="Strong Sell" || status1=="Sell") ) 
{

}
```

Expected below conditions.

> Alert="0"

and

> cci<-80

and

> either of RSI=="sell or ADX=="sell

and

> either  Status strong sell or sell

Please have a look at your end and let me know if anything missed here.

Can anyone correct me if I am wrong.

All Alert, CCI, RSI ADX And Status1 are all cell values in google sheet. there is no syntax error in my statement the result should be like my expectation.

Expected below conditions.

> Alert="0"

and

> cci<-80

and

> either of RSI=="sell or ADX=="sell

and

> either  Status strong sell or sell

Comment: Please provide at least one sample that your code did not satisfy expectation

Comment: `Cci<-80` should be `Cci <= 80`

Comment: @Mamun it could be that `Cci` is supposed to be less than negative 80...  (which is why no syntax error is thrown)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of comments to make:

1. Use `===` instead of `==`, otherwise type coercion is taking place and you could run into [unexpected results](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)
2. Use `<=` instead of `<-`, which is I'm assuming a typo.
3. If you're struggling to reason about a complex predicate, why not break it down into smaller methods. For example, `status1=="Strong Sell" || status1=="Sell"` could be a method called `isSellOrStrongSell(arg)`, this way you only have to reason about that predicate, you could even test that in isolation and then introduce it into your more complex predicate. I can make no assumptions about your problem space but that's how I tend to build up these more complex scenarios.

Comment: can i use like this.  IF (RSI=="Sell" || ADX=="Sell") && (Alert==0 && Cci<=80) && (status1=="Strong Sell"||status1=="Sell")

Comment: `&& (Alert==0 && Cci<=80) &&` is the same as `&& Alert==0 && Cci<=80 &&`. No need for the round bracets.

Comment: @YannickMeeus those `round bracets` are called `parentheses` :)

Comment: @tehhowch Largely depends on which [side of the ocean](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/parentheses-and-brackets) you're on, I've referred to them both as parens and brackets but my brain farted when I was writing my earlier comment so brackets they became :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Cci less than or equal to 80? If so it should be like this:

`Cci <= 80`

Comment: Yes Cci <=80 .. in my command there is no any syntax error i would like to confirm the logic will give as per my expectations are not need to confirm

Comment: @MuraliPujari no syntax error was thrown since `<-80` interprets as `less than negative 80`